# Creating a new file without using a ServletContext

Tags: servlets

Assume I want to write to a new file created within the space of my webapp.

One way would be use `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` and use that String to create a new file on the server. However, often I come across advice like not using `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")`.

Can someone please let me know of another way to write a new file within my webapp?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have some configuration property containing the absolute path of a directory outside of the webapp and web server path, read this path from the configuration property, and write to this directory.

To serve files from this directory, write a servlet that takes the name or ID of this file as parameter, reads the file from the directory, and sends its content to the response.

This will

- work even if the app is deployed as a war file and never unzipped to the file system
- allow you to redeploy the next version of the app or server without deleting all the uploaded/created files
- allow you to add whatever control you want on the uploaded/created files, instead of making them available to everyone

In short, treat these files as data, stored in a database which happens to be the file system instead of a SQL database.

Comment: Thanks JB for your answer. However, in case I am deploying to a server where I cannot be sure of the absolute path of a directory, then what can i do to write the file.